# Match comps to html pixel perfect

Tags: html, css

Is there a program that will show you guides, rulers so you can match your html layout in css to your Photoshop comp. What is best practices. 
Right now I'm doing screen shots and using rectangle tool to get my measurements from the screen shot and see if they match the comp but this is taking so much time. I'm thinking there must be a program or something that can show rulers or measurements or even comp overlays with measurements to fine tune your css pixel measurements to.

Comment: I have used the Pixel Perfect extension, as suggested by thirtydot and that works fine. However: this will only give you an exact design in Firefox. Every other browser might be a pixel (or 2) off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Pixel Perfect extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pixel-perfect/

> Pixel Perfect is a Firefox/Firebug extension that allows web
>   developers and designers to easily overlay a web composition over top
>   of the developed HTML.

Comment: Do you know how to keep the layer on when you reload the page. It keeps turning it off when I reload the page. Which is not the end of the world but tis a little frustrating to have to keep turning it on.

Comment: It doesn't "turn off" for me - the overlay is still there even after I reload the page. I just tested it with Firefox 5 and the most recent stable versions of Firebug/Pixel Perfect. Try making a [new Firefox profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles) and installing only those extensions.

Comment: Ah if you stay on the pixel perfect tab and reload it stays there but if you move to the html tab and reload then you have to go back and turn on the layer again for the pixel perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I find the FireFox MeasureIt tool handy for things like this:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/measureit/

Answer (score 0):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pixel-perfect/ as it was said before. And btw, you can measure distances in photoshop as well: sometimes you just need a value, not messing around with pixel perfect. Use rulers and the Ruler Tool (Shift+I until you get it) in PS. I combine measurements in PS and PixelPerfect addon in my work.